# What's the key of this WW2 lock?

Tags: wordplay, letters

In the Imperial War Museum in London, there's a box with a Directional Padlock, no one has ever opened it, however they found a letter next to it but no one can open the box even with that letter.

> I tried to save them, I warned them that they would attack from the
>   left. They always attack from the left side.
>
> The captain always told me that I was his right hand and that he would
>   trust my word, but in the most critical situation he left me alone.
>
> Why did you insist so much on defending the bridge fort on the right
>   side? Unfortunately, I could never ask him.   Sure, they took me for a
>   madman but I was right. After that I left the army, and the country.
>
> Javier Rodriguez.

What is the key to open the Directional Lock?

Comment: Is this an actual lock that was actually used in WWII, or is it one you came up with for the site? The tags might change a bit depending on the scenario.

Comment: @Brandon_J Think of it as a modern directional lock, old ones may be confusing, I already said it's only right and left if that helps...

Comment: Thanks for the response, TraaZ! I ask not for _solving_ this puzzle but rather for _tagging and organizing_ the puzzle, which is fairly important on this site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The letter, being from Javier Rodriguez,

> was originally written in Spanish.

This means that

> instances of "left" and "right" that don't refer to direction would not have been there in the original Spanish (Spanish has different homographs than English).

Therefore we must ignore the phrases

> "he left me alone", "I was right", "I left the army"

Which leaves

> **left, left, right, right**

as the directions that unlock the lock.

Comment: Clever idea. I have a feeling that this is the intended solution, but something seems...I don't know....(to borrow a word from Gareth) unsatisfying about the question if this is the solution.

Comment: You got it! However it's not that "the original" was in spanish, Javier just would read it in a different way (in spanish) but thats not really important.

Comment: @Brandon_J I said it was very simple, just had to think different instead of think too hard.

Answer (score 2):

It seems too straightforward, but...

> Using Right and Left in the message in the order it is written, would the key be: **left, left, right, left, right, right, left**

Comment: Nope, a lot of people tried that already!

Answer (score 2):

Ok so first of all there's no reason to include this in the letter:

> Javier Rodriguez.

Keeping that in mind I assume this has something to do with the riddle.

> I've tried to find an anagram but found nothing.

So here's my shot:

> I've checked how many words start with L or R, and only the words "Left" and "Right" 
> do that, except one more: "Rodriguez". 
> Maybe this is the solution? 
>  
>
> *L-L-R-L-R-R-L-* **R**

Comment: You're totally right about the first thing, but that's not the solution :s

Answer (score 2):

My solution is

> LRLR RRLR RRLR LLR LLR

**Reasoning:**
As [Fenec T points out](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/83756/44845), the name is probably important somehow. "Javier Rodriguez" sounds like a Spanish name to me, and the Spanish for "Left" is "Izquierda", and for "Right" is "Derecha".  As such:

> I have taken words that *start* with "I" (on the **left** of the work) and words that *end* with "D" (on the **right** of the word)

This gives us the following:

> **I** trie**d** to save them, **I** warne**d** them that they woul**d** attack from the left. They always attack from the left side.
>
>  The captain always tol**d** me that **I** was his right han**d** and that he woul**d** trust my wor**d**, but **i**n the most critical situation he left me alone.
>
>  Why di**d** you **i**nsist so much on defending the bridge fort on the rightside? Unfortunately, **I** coul**d** never ask him. Sure, they took me for a madman but **I** was right. After that **I** left the army, an**d** the country.
>
>  Javier Rodriguez.

Comment: You got something there that is very important to solve it, but it's way easier than that.

Comment: @TraaZ apparently not, it would seem.

Answer (score 0):

> This is just a wild guess but is it **Left, Left, Right, Right, Left?** because sometimes   when he says a direction it said that that it is always left so that's the first 
>  direction. The second the captain said he was his right hand man but ACTUALLY "*Left*"  him. And the rest of the directions come from the rest of the letter.

Comment: No, it's an interesting way of seeing it but it's not the answer, sorry :s

Comment: Is it just left and right or is there an up and down too?

Comment: only left and right

Answer (score 0):

Updated Answer- Attempt 2:

> Left, Left, Left, Open

A2-Reason:

> Javier is a lieutenant, he warned the of an attack on the left flank. **(LEFT)** The captain said he was the right hand (ie XO), and that he trusted him, so he gives him a few men and says defend the left.  But the captain went to the right leaving the lieutenant alone to defend the left. **(LEFT)** In the end, the left was attacked and overrun, allowing the right to be flanked, so the lieutenant left the service.**(LEFT)**

My First shot:

First:

> Right - I tried to warn them that they always attack from the left...each of the answers has started with Left, everyone is attacking from the Left, so Right is the correct response

Then:

> Left - He said I was his right hand but he left his right hand alone thus he didn't use the right, go Left

Then:

> Right - Paraphrase: You insist on defending the right (blocking a right push), but I was right, yet I selected left...(should have selected Right)

Then:

> the signature, signing off...which means hit the unlock button.

**Final:**

> Right, Left, Right, Enter

Alternatively:

> Depending on whether the captain was setting the combination or trying to open the lock - for the second one it would be Right.  because he left the right alone he failed....Right, Right, Right, Enter

Comment: It's wrong, sorry. I don't want to give hints cause it'd make it very easy but... don't think too hard, think different.

Answer (score 0):

Answer

> L,R,R,L

Reason

> Discarding sentences with negative connotations.
>  Using:
>  They always attack from the left side.
>  The captain always told me that I was his right hand...
>  Why did you insist so much on defending the bridge fort on the right side? 
>  I left the army, and the country.

Comment: Sorry it's not that :s